# Parsing HTML of betting sites (ValueError: No tables found)

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, request, html-parsing

I would like to get the table with all coefficients from the following url: https://www.parimatch.com/en/sport/futbol/liga-chempionov-uefa

I have already tried both with pandas and requests, without success (ValueError: No tables found). Can someone help me out?

Here the code that I have tried:

```
url = 'https://www.parimatch.com/en/sport/futbol/liga-chempionov-uefa'

header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=header)

dfs = pd.read_html(r.text, )
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup is the most common package specifically designed for parsing HTML

Comment: i think you did not pass the security check.

Answer (score 0):

urllib.request.urlretrieve
maybe? use this code to define your link
python need to know what you are gonna download from web.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Suggestions should rather be posted as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I am sorry. I didin't know that